# CSS create a selector for a new element

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Here's a tricky one, I need to select the elements within the `class="price_code"` however it needs only be applicable if the `data-product-id` is equal to `447`. How can this be done using CSS? Or would it need to be a Javascript solution?

```
<span class="price_code" data-product-id="447">
   <span class="Price-amount amount">
      <span class="Price-currencySymbol">£</span>&nbsp;0
   </span>
</span>
```

I understand that normally you'd just specify `.price_code` to select the class using CSS, however how can I specify that the `data-product-id` needs to `447`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
.price_code[data-product-id="447"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="price_code" data-product-id="447">
   <span class="Price-amount amount">
      <span class="Price-currencySymbol">£</span>&nbsp;0
</span>
</span>

<span class="price_code" data-product-id="448">
   <span class="Price-amount amount">
      <span class="Price-currencySymbol">£</span>&nbsp;1
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you!